# unity tweak tool not working in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, unity-tweak-tool

I can't open Unity Tweak Tool in my Ubuntu 15.04 after upgrade. It says:

> **The following schema is missing**
>
> *com.canonical.unity.webapps*
>
> In order to work properly, Unity Tweak Tool recommends you install the
>   necessary packages

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it by installing the following package(s):

- [`unity-webapps-service`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/unity-webapps-service)
- and perhaps [`unity-webapps-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/unity-webapps-common)

You can install them with `sudo apt-get install <PACKAGE-NAME>`.